Finding Gain of the Analog circuit
I have been finding the input referred noise of the circuit shown below. Here, I am using this approach, please correct me, and help

I found out the output referred noise of the circuit to be \$ 4KT\gamma(g_{m_1}+g_{m_2}+g_{m_3}+g_{m_4}+g_{m_5}+g_{m_6})\$, as the tail node is virtually grounded in the differential picture so I assumed \$M_O\$ and \$M_A\$ won't be contributing any noise.
I tried finding out the gain of the circuit to refer this noise to input. I divided the circuit into two equal halves (Conventional approach). Then I tried to find the looking up impedance from the drain of \$M_1\$, \$R_{out}\$. As we know usually gain of differential amplifier = \$g_{m_1}\times R_{out}\$.
For Rout I have in parallel \$1/g_{m_5}\$ from \$M_5\$ and something from the \$M_3\$. This is where I land in trouble due to the cross check made between the gates. 


Search for the input impedance of a cross-coupled pair ($M_3$ and $M_4$). Hint: it is negative!

Oh, I searched about it, and using small signal analysis, found out it to be -2/gm (In the case gm3 and gm4 are equal), parallel combination otherwise. So should the look up impedance from the drain be parallel of 1/gm5, -2/gm3 ?

Also when adding the two resistances, if they are in negative, shall we add with sign?

The Cross-Coupled Pair
The cross-coupled pair you see in this circuit is widely used for many purposes. It presents a negative resistance which is useful in oscillators and amplifiers to boost the gain. I suggest these wonderful articles from professor Razavi on the circuit and its usage:
https://doi.org/10.1109/MSSC.2014.2329234
https://doi.org/10.1109/MSSC.2014.2352532
https://doi.org/10.1109/MSSC.2014.2369332

The Question at Hand

The output noise current is indeed the summation of the noise from all the transistors in the signal path. However, we need to be careful when taking the differential output noise. First of all, under full symmetricity, noise of \$M_0\$ and \$M_A\$ appear in common-mode and do not contribute to the differential output. As you have correctly found out, the total differential output noise will be the summation of the noise currents from both of the branches: \$ \overline{i^2_{n,out}} = 4kT\gamma (g_{m_1} + g_{m_2} + g_{m_3} + g_{m_4} + g_{m_5} + g_{m_6}) \$.
What is the output resistance in this circuit? Let us find the total output conductance. We have a \$ g_{m_5} \$ term from the diode connected devices and a \$ -g_{m_3}/2 \$ differential term from the cross-coupled pair, which becomes \$ -g_{m_3} \$ single ended. This yields the differential gain as: \$ A_v = g_{m_1} / (g_{m_5} - g_{m_3} + g_{ds_1}) \$.
While finding the output resistance is a good practice, you do not need it in this case! Why not simply take the output noise current and divide it by the total transconductance?! The input-referred noise voltage \$ \overline{v^2_{n,in}} \$ then can be calculated as \$ \overline{i^2_{n,out}}/G_m^2 \$:
$$\overline{v^2_{n,in}} = \frac{4kT\gamma (g_{m_1} + g_{m_2} + g_{m_3} + g_{m_4} + g_{m_5} + g_{m_6})}{g^2_{m_1}}.$$
Using the voltage gain method should yield identical results, since the \$R_{out}^2\$ terms will cancel out.


I am not able to understand why the −3 / 2 became −3 when single ended, the rational behind this. If we are solving like this, why did not we take the 6 as well ?

Think of $-g_{m_3}/2$ as a resistor you want to split in half so that the middle point is a virtual ground. Then, each segment would have half the resistance of the original one and hence double the conductance.
